# Filtered Table Data is not returning to its previous state after removing the filtered item on the webpage

Tags: angular, typescript

I used ng-multiselect dropdown to get data from db, these dropdowns are used to filter a data table on the webpage. When you select a dropdown, the item filters the table, but when you un-select this filtered item on the webpage, the data table does not return to its initial state. The table data disappears from the webpage . I want a to render a condition that when I un-select the item, the table data returns to its initial state.

.ts

```
  tableData: ITransactionDetail[];
  data: ITransactionDetail[];

 selectedItems = [];
 selectedIds = [];

dropdownSettings: IDropdownSettings;

 this.dropdownSettings = {
  singleSelection: false,
  idField: 'id',
  textField: 'transactionType',
  selectAllText: 'Select All',
  unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
  itemsShowLimit: 3,
  allowSearchFilter: true
  };

  onItemSelect(item: any) {
  this.selectedIds.push(item.id);
  this.resetTable();
   }
  onSelectAll() {
  this.selectedIds = this.data.map(x => x.id);
  this.resetTable();
   }
  onDeSelectAll() {
  this.selectedIds = [];
  this.resetTable();
  }
 onItemDeSelect(item: any) {
 this.selectedIds.splice(this.selectedIds.indexOf(item.id), 1);
 this.resetTable();
  }
  resetTable() {
 this.tableData = [...this.data.filter(x => this.selectedIds.includes(x.id))];
 }
```

.html

```
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
       transactionType
       <div>
      <ng-multiselect-dropdown
      [placeholder]="'Select'"
      [settings]="dropdownSettings4"
      [data]="data"
      (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
      (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
      (onDeSelect)="onItemDeSelect($event)"
       >
      </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
    </div>
  </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.transactionType }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
onDeSelectAll() {
    this.selectedIds = [];
    this.tableData = [...this.data];
}

onItemDeSelect(item: any) {
   this.selectedIds.splice(this.selectedIds.indexOf(item.id), 1);
   if (this.selectedIds.length > 0) {
     this.resetTable();
   } else {
     this.tableData = [...this.data];
   }
}
```

Check the [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-multiselect-dropdown-anngw1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)